# .htaccess redirect from domain to another

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ho can i redirect all requests for pattern *host.com/** to *otherhost.com/**

For example all request for *host.com/page1* need to be rewritten to *otherhost.com/page1*

The difficult part is that requests to *host.com* itself (home page) shouls not be rewritten.

This is what i tried to do
    `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://otherhost.com/$1 [R=301,L]`
But keeps rewriting all request including the homepage

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add some conditions :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://otherhost.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =host.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/
RewriteRule . http://otherhost.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =host.com` checks whether the host is `host.com`.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/` checks whether the requested page is **not** the "index". (If this is what you mean by "requests to host.com itself (home page) shouls not be rewritten")

`R=301` states it should send a `HTTP 301 Moved Permanently` header when redirecting.

`NE` states it should not escape special characters. (e.g. `?` escaped to `%3f`)
**This is important!** If you don't specify this, many URLs will be wrong. (e.g. `/blah.php?id=1` will be redirected to `/blah.php%3fid%3d1`, which is wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index.html)?$
RewriteRule (.*)  http://otherhost.com/$1  [R=301,L]
```